# Can any packages be removed from the debian minimal image?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

**Baackstory**: I am trying to create a customized Linux distribution for my project.
My first thought was LFS(Linux from Scratch) and I had almost completed that when my (unreasonable)academic supervisor said that he needed a package manager with my LFS. When I said that installing a package manager would defeat the entire purpose of doing a LFS, he told me to present him the project with a complete manager either by installing a package manager in the LFS build or start over and build a new one with a package manager in mind.

**My approach**: Keep working on the LFS without a package manager while also building a new one starting from Debian. I do not wish to spoil my three months of effort (trying to compile a package and failing and trying again after realizing and correcting my mistake).

**My question**:
 1. Is it viable installing a package manager in a LFS build? (My guess: NO)
2. What packages can be removed from the minimal installation of debian? I know this can be done as I remember one of my seniors showing me a running debian installation with 2.x GB of space while my minimal installation (with ssh and screen installed by me) is of 5.5G.

**TL;DR:** Unreasonable supervisor, wants a package manager in LFS, will change my project form LFS to a debian based distro. What can be removed from the minimal install of debian.

Here is the list of packages installed:

```
acl/stable,now 2.2.53-4 amd64 
adduser/stable,now 3.118 all 
anacron/stable,now 2.3-28 amd64 
apparmor/stable,now 2.13.2-10 amd64 
apt-listchanges/stable,now 3.19 all 
apt-utils/stable,stable,now 1.8.2.2 amd64 
apt/stable,stable,now 1.8.2.2 amd64 
avahi-autoipd/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
avahi-daemon/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
base-files/stable,now 10.3+deb10u8 amd64 
base-passwd/stable,now 3.5.46 amd64 
bash-completion/stable,now 1:2.8-6 all 
bash/stable,now 5.0-4 amd64 
bc/stable,now 1.07.1-2+b1 amd64 
bind9-host/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
bluetooth/stable,stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 all 
bluez/stable,stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64 
bsdmainutils/stable,now 11.1.2+b1 amd64 
bsdutils/stable,now 1:2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
busybox/stable,now 1:1.30.1-4 amd64 
bzip2/stable,now 1.0.6-9.2~deb10u1 amd64 
ca-certificates/stable,stable-updates,now 20200601~deb10u2 all 
colord-data/stable,now 1.4.3-4 all 
colord/stable,now 1.4.3-4 amd64 
console-setup-linux/stable,now 1.193~deb10u1 all 
console-setup/stable,now 1.193~deb10u1 all 
coreutils/stable,now 8.30-3 amd64 
cpio/stable,now 2.12+dfsg-9 amd64 
crda/stable,now 3.18-1 amd64 
cron/stable,now 3.0pl1-134+deb10u1 amd64 
cups-browsed/stable,now 1.21.6-5 amd64 
cups-bsd/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
cups-client/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
cups-common/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 all 
cups-core-drivers/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
cups-daemon/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
cups-filters-core-drivers/stable,now 1.21.6-5 amd64 
cups-filters/stable,now 1.21.6-5 amd64 
cups-ipp-utils/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
cups-ppdc/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
cups-server-common/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 all 
cups/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
dash/stable,now 0.5.10.2-5 amd64 
dbus-user-session/stable,now 1.12.20-0+deb10u1 amd64 
dbus/stable,now 1.12.20-0+deb10u1 amd64 
dc/stable,now 1.07.1-2+b1 amd64 
dconf-gsettings-backend/stable,now 0.30.1-2 amd64 
dconf-service/stable,now 0.30.1-2 amd64 
debconf-i18n/stable,now 1.5.71 all 
debconf/stable,now 1.5.71 all 
debian-archive-keyring/stable,now 2019.1 all 
debian-faq/stable,now 9.0 all 
debianutils/stable,now 4.8.6.1 amd64 
dictionaries-common/stable,now 1.28.1 all 
diffutils/stable,now 1:3.7-3 amd64 
discover-data/stable,now 2.2013.01.11 all 
discover/stable,now 2.1.2-8 amd64 
distro-info-data/stable,now 0.41+deb10u3 all 
dmidecode/stable,now 3.2-1 amd64 
dmsetup/stable,now 2:1.02.155-3 amd64 
doc-debian/stable,now 6.4 all 
dpkg/stable,now 1.19.7 amd64 
e2fsprogs/stable,now 1.44.5-1+deb10u3 amd64 
eject/stable,now 2.1.5+deb1+cvs20081104-13.2 amd64 
emacsen-common/stable,now 3.0.4 all 
fdisk/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
file/stable,now 1:5.35-4+deb10u2 amd64 
findutils/stable,now 4.6.0+git+20190209-2 amd64 
firmware-linux-free/stable,now 3.4 all 
fontconfig-config/stable,now 2.13.1-2 all 
fonts-dejavu-core/stable,now 2.37-1 all 
fonts-droid-fallback/stable,now 1:6.0.1r16-1.1 all 
fonts-noto-mono/stable,now 20181227-1 all 
foomatic-db-compressed-ppds/stable,now 20181217-2 all 
foomatic-db-engine/stable,now 4.0.13-3 amd64 
gcc-8-base/stable,now 8.3.0-6 amd64 
gdbm-l10n/stable,now 1.18.1-4 all 
geoip-database/stable,now 20181108-1 all 
gettext-base/stable,now 0.19.8.1-9 amd64 
ghostscript/stable,stable,now 9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 amd64 
gir1.2-glib-2.0/stable,now 1.58.3-2 amd64 
gpgv/stable,now 2.2.12-1+deb10u1 amd64 
grep/stable,now 3.3-1 amd64 
groff-base/stable,now 1.22.4-3 amd64 
grub-common/stable,now 2.02+dfsg1-20+deb10u4 amd64 
grub-pc-bin/stable,now 2.02+dfsg1-20+deb10u4 amd64 
grub-pc/stable,now 2.02+dfsg1-20+deb10u4 amd64 
grub2-common/stable,now 2.02+dfsg1-20+deb10u4 amd64 
gsfonts/stable,now 1:8.11+urwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4.4 all 
gzip/stable,now 1.9-3 amd64 
hdparm/stable,now 9.58+ds-1 amd64 
hostname/stable,now 3.21 amd64 
hp-ppd/stable,now 0.9-0.3 all 
hplip-data/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 all 
hplip/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 amd64 
iamerican/stable,now 3.4.00-6 all 
ibritish/stable,now 3.4.00-6 all 
ienglish-common/stable,now 3.4.00-6 all 
ifupdown/stable,now 0.8.35 amd64 
init-system-helpers/stable,now 1.56+nmu1 all 
init/stable,now 1.56+nmu1 amd64 
initramfs-tools-core/stable,now 0.133+deb10u1 all 
initramfs-tools/stable,now 0.133+deb10u1 all 
installation-report/stable,now 2.71 all 
iproute2/stable,now 4.20.0-2+deb10u1 amd64 
iptables/stable,now 1.8.2-4 amd64 
iputils-ping/stable,now 3:20180629-2+deb10u1 amd64 
isc-dhcp-client/stable,now 4.4.1-2 amd64 
isc-dhcp-common/stable,now 4.4.1-2 amd64 
iso-codes/stable,now 4.2-1 all 
ispell/stable,now 3.4.00-6+b1 amd64 
iw/stable,now 5.0.1-1 amd64 
kbd/stable,now 2.0.4-4 amd64 
keyboard-configuration/stable,now 1.193~deb10u1 all 
klibc-utils/stable,now 2.0.6-1 amd64 
kmod/stable,now 26-1 amd64 
krb5-locales/stable,stable,now 1.17-3+deb10u1 all 
laptop-detect/stable,now 0.16 all 
less/stable,now 487-0.1+b1 amd64 
libacl1/stable,now 2.2.53-4 amd64 
libapparmor1/stable,now 2.13.2-10 amd64 
libapt-inst2.0/stable,stable,now 1.8.2.2 amd64 
libapt-pkg5.0/stable,stable,now 1.8.2.2 amd64 
libargon2-1/stable,now 0~20171227-0.2 amd64 
libasound2-data/stable,now 1.1.8-1 all 
libasound2/stable,now 1.1.8-1 amd64 
libattr1/stable,now 1:2.4.48-4 amd64 
libaudit-common/stable,now 1:2.8.4-3 all 
libaudit1/stable,now 1:2.8.4-3 amd64 
libavahi-client3/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
libavahi-common-data/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
libavahi-common3/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
libavahi-core7/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
libavahi-glib1/stable,now 0.7-4+b1 amd64 
libbind9-161/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libblkid1/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
libbsd0/stable,now 0.9.1-2 amd64 
libbz2-1.0/stable,now 1.0.6-9.2~deb10u1 amd64 
libc-bin/stable,now 2.28-10 amd64 
libc-l10n/stable,now 2.28-10 all 
libc6/stable,now 2.28-10 amd64 
libcairo2/stable,now 1.16.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 
libcap-ng0/stable,now 0.7.9-2 amd64 
libcap2-bin/stable,now 1:2.25-2 amd64 
libcap2/stable,now 1:2.25-2 amd64 
libcolord2/stable,now 1.4.3-4 amd64 
libcolorhug2/stable,now 1.4.3-4 amd64 
libcom-err2/stable,now 1.44.5-1+deb10u3 amd64 
libcryptsetup12/stable,now 2:2.1.0-5+deb10u2 amd64 
libcups2/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
libcupsfilters1/stable,now 1.21.6-5 amd64 
libcupsimage2/stable,now 2.2.10-6+deb10u4 amd64 
libcurl3-gnutls/stable,stable,now 7.64.0-4+deb10u1 amd64 
libdaemon0/stable,now 0.14-7 amd64 
libdb5.3/stable,now 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.5 amd64 
libdbus-1-3/stable,now 1.12.20-0+deb10u1 amd64 
libdconf1/stable,now 0.30.1-2 amd64 
libdebconfclient0/stable,now 0.249 amd64 
libdevmapper1.02.1/stable,now 2:1.02.155-3 amd64 
libdiscover2/stable,now 2.1.2-8 amd64 
libdns-export1104/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libdns1104/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libdrm-amdgpu1/stable,now 2.4.97-1 amd64 
libdrm-common/stable,now 2.4.97-1 all 
libdrm-intel1/stable,now 2.4.97-1 amd64 
libdrm-nouveau2/stable,now 2.4.97-1 amd64 
libdrm-radeon1/stable,now 2.4.97-1 amd64 
libdrm2/stable,now 2.4.97-1 amd64 
libdw1/stable,now 0.176-1.1 amd64 
libedit2/stable,now 3.1-20181209-1 amd64 
libefiboot1/stable,now 37-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libefivar1/stable,now 37-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libelf1/stable,now 0.176-1.1 amd64 
libestr0/stable,now 0.1.10-2.1 amd64 
libexif12/stable,stable,now 0.6.21-5.1+deb10u5 amd64 
libexpat1/stable,stable,now 2.2.6-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libext2fs2/stable,now 1.44.5-1+deb10u3 amd64 
libfastjson4/stable,now 0.99.8-2 amd64 
libfdisk1/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
libffi6/stable,now 3.2.1-9 amd64 
libfontconfig1/stable,now 2.13.1-2 amd64 
libfontembed1/stable,now 1.21.6-5 amd64 
libfontenc1/stable,now 1:1.1.3-1+b2 amd64 
libfreetype6/stable,stable,now 2.9.1-3+deb10u2 amd64 
libfstrm0/stable,now 0.4.0-1 amd64 
libfuse2/stable,now 2.9.9-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libgcc1/stable,now 1:8.3.0-6 amd64 
libgcrypt20/stable,now 1.8.4-5 amd64 
libgd3/stable,now 2.2.5-5.2 amd64 
libgdbm-compat4/stable,now 1.18.1-4 amd64 
libgdbm6/stable,now 1.18.1-4 amd64 
libgeoip1/stable,now 1.6.12-1 amd64 
libgirepository-1.0-1/stable,now 1.58.3-2 amd64 
libgl1-mesa-dri/stable,now 18.3.6-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libgl1/stable,now 1.1.0-1 amd64 
libglapi-mesa/stable,now 18.3.6-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libglib2.0-0/stable,now 2.58.3-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libglib2.0-data/stable,now 2.58.3-2+deb10u2 all 
libglvnd0/stable,now 1.1.0-1 amd64 
libglx-mesa0/stable,now 18.3.6-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libglx0/stable,now 1.1.0-1 amd64 
libgmp10/stable,now 2:6.1.2+dfsg-4 amd64 
libgnutls30/stable,now 3.6.7-4+deb10u6 amd64 
libgpg-error0/stable,now 1.35-1 amd64 
libgphoto2-6/stable,now 2.5.22-3 amd64 
libgphoto2-l10n/stable,now 2.5.22-3 all 
libgphoto2-port12/stable,now 2.5.22-3 amd64 
libgs9-common/stable,stable,now 9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 all 
libgs9/stable,stable,now 9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 amd64 
libgssapi-krb5-2/stable,stable,now 1.17-3+deb10u1 amd64 
libgudev-1.0-0/stable,now 232-2 amd64 
libgusb2/stable,now 0.3.0-1 amd64 
libgutenprint-common/stable,now 5.3.1-7 all 
libgutenprint9/stable,now 5.3.1-7 amd64 
libhogweed4/stable,now 3.4.1-1 amd64 
libhpmud0/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 amd64 
libice6/stable,now 2:1.0.9-2 amd64 
libicu63/stable,stable,now 63.1-6+deb10u1 amd64 
libidn11/stable,now 1.33-2.2 amd64 
libidn2-0/stable,stable,now 2.0.5-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libieee1284-3/stable,now 0.2.11-13 amd64 
libijs-0.35/stable,now 0.35-14 amd64 
libimagequant0/stable,now 2.12.2-1.1 amd64 
libip4tc0/stable,now 1.8.2-4 amd64 
libip6tc0/stable,now 1.8.2-4 amd64 
libiptc0/stable,now 1.8.2-4 amd64 
libisc-export1100/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libisc1100/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libisccc161/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libisccfg163/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
libiw30/stable,now 30~pre9-13 amd64 
libjbig0/stable,now 2.1-3.1+b2 amd64 
libjbig2dec0/stable,now 0.16-1 amd64 
libjim0.77/stable,now 0.77+dfsg0-3 amd64 
libjpeg62-turbo/stable,now 1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libjson-c3/stable,stable,now 0.12.1+ds-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libk5crypto3/stable,stable,now 1.17-3+deb10u1 amd64 
libkeyutils1/stable,now 1.6-6 amd64 
libklibc/stable,now 2.0.6-1 amd64 
libkmod2/stable,now 26-1 amd64 
libkrb5-3/stable,stable,now 1.17-3+deb10u1 amd64 
libkrb5support0/stable,stable,now 1.17-3+deb10u1 amd64 
liblcms2-2/stable,now 2.9-3 amd64 
liblcms2-utils/stable,now 2.9-3 amd64 
libldap-2.4-2/stable,now 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u6 amd64 
libldap-common/stable,now 2.4.47+dfsg-3+deb10u6 all 
libllvm7/stable,now 1:7.0.1-8+deb10u2 amd64 
liblmdb0/stable,now 0.9.22-1 amd64 
liblocale-gettext-perl/stable,now 1.07-3+b4 amd64 
liblockfile-bin/stable,now 1.14-1.1 amd64 
liblognorm5/stable,now 2.0.5-1 amd64 
liblouis-data/stable,now 3.8.0-2 all 
liblouis17/stable,now 3.8.0-2 amd64 
liblouisutdml-bin/stable,now 2.7.0-5+b1 amd64 
liblouisutdml-data/stable,now 2.7.0-5 all 
liblouisutdml8/stable,now 2.7.0-5+b1 amd64 
libltdl7/stable,now 2.4.6-9 amd64 
liblwres161/stable,now 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u3 amd64 
liblz4-1/stable,now 1.8.3-1 amd64 
liblzma5/stable,now 5.2.4-1 amd64 
libmagic-mgc/stable,now 1:5.35-4+deb10u2 amd64 
libmagic1/stable,now 1:5.35-4+deb10u2 amd64 
libmariadb3/stable,now 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1 amd64 
libmnl0/stable,now 1.0.4-2 amd64 
libmount1/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
libmpdec2/stable,now 2.4.2-2 amd64 
libncurses6/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libncursesw6/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libnetfilter-conntrack3/stable,now 1.0.7-1 amd64 
libnettle6/stable,now 3.4.1-1 amd64 
libnewt0.52/stable,now 0.52.20-8 amd64 
libnfnetlink0/stable,now 1.0.1-3+b1 amd64 
libnftnl11/stable,now 1.1.2-2 amd64 
libnghttp2-14/stable,stable,now 1.36.0-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libnl-3-200/stable,now 3.4.0-1 amd64 
libnl-genl-3-200/stable,now 3.4.0-1 amd64 
libnl-route-3-200/stable,now 3.4.0-1 amd64 
libnspr4/stable,now 2:4.20-1 amd64 
libnss-mdns/stable,now 0.14.1-1 amd64 
libnss-systemd/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
libnss3/stable,stable,now 2:3.42.1-1+deb10u3 amd64 
libopenjp2-7/stable,now 2.3.0-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libp11-kit0/stable,stable,now 0.23.15-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libpam-modules-bin/stable,now 1.3.1-5 amd64 
libpam-modules/stable,now 1.3.1-5 amd64 
libpam-runtime/stable,now 1.3.1-5 all 
libpam-systemd/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
libpam0g/stable,now 1.3.1-5 amd64 
libpaper-utils/stable,now 1.1.28 amd64 
libpaper1/stable,now 1.1.28 amd64 
libpci3/stable,now 1:3.5.2-1 amd64 
libpciaccess0/stable,now 0.14-1 amd64 
libpcre2-8-0/stable,now 10.32-5 amd64 
libpcre3/stable,now 2:8.39-12 amd64 
libpcsclite1/stable,now 1.8.24-1 amd64 
libperl5.28/stable,now 5.28.1-6+deb10u1 amd64 
libpipeline1/stable,now 1.5.1-2 amd64 
libpixman-1-0/stable,now 0.36.0-1 amd64 
libpng16-16/stable,now 1.6.36-6 amd64 
libpolkit-agent-1-0/stable,now 0.105-25 amd64 
libpolkit-backend-1-0/stable,now 0.105-25 amd64 
libpolkit-gobject-1-0/stable,now 0.105-25 amd64 
libpoppler82/stable,now 0.71.0-5 amd64 
libpopt0/stable,now 1.16-12 amd64 
libprocps7/stable,now 2:3.3.15-2 amd64 
libprotobuf-c1/stable,now 1.3.1-1+b1 amd64 
libpsl5/stable,now 0.20.2-2 amd64 
libpython-stdlib/stable,now 2.7.16-1 amd64 
libpython2-stdlib/stable,now 2.7.16-1 amd64 
libpython2.7-minimal/stable,now 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libpython2.7-stdlib/stable,now 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 amd64 
libpython3-stdlib/stable,now 3.7.3-1 amd64 
libpython3.7-minimal/stable,now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libpython3.7-stdlib/stable,now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libpython3.7/stable,now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libqpdf21/stable,now 8.4.0-2 amd64 
libreadline7/stable,now 7.0-5 amd64 
librtmp1/stable,now 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2 amd64 
libsane-common/stable,now 1.0.27-3.2 all 
libsane-hpaio/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 amd64 
libsane/stable,now 1.0.27-3.2 amd64 
libsasl2-2/stable,stable,now 2.1.27+dfsg-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libsasl2-modules-db/stable,stable,now 2.1.27+dfsg-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libsasl2-modules/stable,stable,now 2.1.27+dfsg-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libseccomp2/stable,now 2.3.3-4 amd64 
libselinux1/stable,now 2.8-1+b1 amd64 
libsemanage-common/stable,now 2.8-2 all 
libsemanage1/stable,now 2.8-2 amd64 
libsensors-config/stable,now 1:3.5.0-3 all 
libsensors5/stable,now 1:3.5.0-3 amd64 
libsepol1/stable,now 2.8-1 amd64 
libslang2/stable,now 2.3.2-2 amd64 
libsm6/stable,now 2:1.2.3-1 amd64 
libsmartcols1/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
libsnmp-base/stable,now 5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2 all 
libsnmp30/stable,now 5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2 amd64 
libsqlite3-0/stable,now 3.27.2-3+deb10u1 amd64 
libss2/stable,now 1.44.5-1+deb10u3 amd64 
libssh2-1/stable,now 1.8.0-2.1 amd64 
libssl1.1/stable,now 1.1.1d-0+deb10u6 amd64 
libstdc++6/stable,now 8.3.0-6 amd64 
libsystemd0/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
libtasn1-6/stable,now 4.13-3 amd64 
libtcl8.6/stable,now 8.6.9+dfsg-2 amd64 
libtext-charwidth-perl/stable,now 0.04-7.1+b1 amd64 
libtext-iconv-perl/stable,now 1.7-5+b7 amd64 
libtext-wrapi18n-perl/stable,now 0.06-7.1 all 
libtiff5/stable,now 4.1.0+git191117-2~deb10u2 amd64 
libtinfo6/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 
libtk8.6/stable,now 8.6.9-2 amd64 
libuchardet0/stable,now 0.0.6-3 amd64 
libudev1/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
libunistring2/stable,now 0.9.10-1 amd64 
libusb-0.1-4/stable,now 2:0.1.12-32 amd64 
libusb-1.0-0/stable,now 2:1.0.22-2 amd64 
libutempter0/stable,now 1.1.6-3 amd64 
libuuid1/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
libwebp6/stable,now 0.6.1-2 amd64 
libwebpdemux2/stable,now 0.6.1-2 amd64 
libwebpmux3/stable,now 0.6.1-2 amd64 
libwrap0/stable,now 7.6.q-28 amd64 
libx11-6/stable,now 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libx11-data/stable,now 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1 all 
libx11-xcb1/stable,now 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1 amd64 
libxau6/stable,now 1:1.0.8-1+b2 amd64 
libxaw7/stable,now 2:1.0.13-1+b2 amd64 
libxcb-dri2-0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-dri3-0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-glx0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-present0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-render0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-shape0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-shm0/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb-sync1/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcb1/stable,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 
libxcomposite1/stable,now 1:0.4.4-2 amd64 
libxdamage1/stable,now 1:1.1.4-3+b3 amd64 
libxdmcp6/stable,now 1:1.1.2-3 amd64 
libxext6/stable,now 2:1.3.3-1+b2 amd64 
libxfixes3/stable,now 1:5.0.3-1 amd64 
libxft2/stable,now 2.3.2-2 amd64 
libxi6/stable,now 2:1.7.9-1 amd64 
libxinerama1/stable,now 2:1.1.4-2 amd64 
libxml2/stable,now 2.9.4+dfsg1-7+deb10u1 amd64 
libxmu6/stable,now 2:1.1.2-2+b3 amd64 
libxmuu1/stable,now 2:1.1.2-2+b3 amd64 
libxpm4/stable,now 1:3.5.12-1 amd64 
libxrandr2/stable,now 2:1.5.1-1 amd64 
libxrender1/stable,now 1:0.9.10-1 amd64 
libxshmfence1/stable,now 1.3-1 amd64 
libxss1/stable,now 1:1.2.3-1 amd64 
libxt6/stable,now 1:1.1.5-1+b3 amd64 
libxtables12/stable,now 1.8.2-4 amd64 
libxtst6/stable,now 2:1.2.3-1 amd64 
libxv1/stable,now 2:1.0.11-1 amd64 
libxxf86dga1/stable,now 2:1.1.4-1+b3 amd64 
libxxf86vm1/stable,now 1:1.1.4-1+b2 amd64 
libyaml-0-2/stable,now 0.2.1-1 amd64 
libzstd1/stable,now 1.3.8+dfsg-3+deb10u2 amd64 
linux-base/stable,now 4.6 all 
linux-image-4.19.0-14-amd64/stable,stable,now 4.19.171-2 amd64 
linux-image-amd64/stable,stable,now 4.19+105+deb10u9 amd64 
locales/stable,now 2.28-10 all 
login/stable,now 1:4.5-1.1 amd64 
logrotate/stable,now 3.14.0-4 amd64 
lsb-base/stable,now 10.2019051400 all 
lsb-release/stable,now 10.2019051400 all 
lsof/stable,now 4.91+dfsg-1 amd64 
man-db/stable,now 2.8.5-2 amd64 
manpages/stable,now 4.16-2 all 
mariadb-common/stable,now 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1 all 
mawk/stable,now 1.3.3-17+b3 amd64 
mime-support/stable,now 3.62 all 
mount/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
mscompress/stable,now 0.4-3+b1 amd64 
mysql-common/stable,now 5.8+1.0.5 all 
nano/stable,now 3.2-3 amd64 
ncurses-base/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 all 
ncurses-bin/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 amd64 
ncurses-term/stable,now 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 all 
netbase/stable,now 5.6 all 
netcat-traditional/stable,now 1.10-41.1 amd64 
openprinting-ppds/stable,now 20181217-2 all 
openssh-client/stable,now 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2 amd64 
openssh-server/stable,now 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2 amd64 
openssh-sftp-server/stable,now 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2 amd64 
openssl/stable,now 1.1.1d-0+deb10u6 amd64 
os-prober/stable,now 1.77 amd64 
passwd/stable,now 1:4.5-1.1 amd64 
pciutils/stable,now 1:3.5.2-1 amd64 
perl-base/stable,now 5.28.1-6+deb10u1 amd64 
perl-modules-5.28/stable,now 5.28.1-6+deb10u1 all 
perl/stable,now 5.28.1-6+deb10u1 amd64 
policykit-1/stable,now 0.105-25 amd64 
poppler-data/stable,now 0.4.9-2 all 
poppler-utils/stable,now 0.71.0-5 amd64 
powermgmt-base/stable,now 1.34 all 
powertop/stable,now 2.8-1+b2 amd64 
printer-driver-all/stable,now 0.20170124 all 
printer-driver-brlaser/stable,now 4-1 amd64 
printer-driver-c2050/stable,now 0.3b-8 amd64 
printer-driver-c2esp/stable,now 27-4 amd64 
printer-driver-cjet/stable,now 0.8.9-7 amd64 
printer-driver-dymo/stable,now 1.4.0-8 amd64 
printer-driver-escpr/stable,now 1.6.33-1 amd64 
printer-driver-foo2zjs-common/stable,now 20171202dfsg0-2 all 
printer-driver-foo2zjs/stable,now 20171202dfsg0-2 amd64 
printer-driver-fujixerox/stable,now 1.1.0+ds-3 amd64 
printer-driver-gutenprint/stable,now 5.3.1-7 amd64 
printer-driver-hpcups/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 amd64 
printer-driver-hpijs/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 amd64 
printer-driver-m2300w/stable,now 0.51-13 amd64 
printer-driver-min12xxw/stable,now 0.0.9-11 amd64 
printer-driver-pnm2ppa/stable,now 1.13-9 amd64 
printer-driver-postscript-hp/stable,now 3.18.12+dfsg0-2 amd64 
printer-driver-ptouch/stable,now 1.4.2-3 amd64 
printer-driver-pxljr/stable,now 1.4+repack0-5 amd64 
printer-driver-sag-gdi/stable,now 0.1-7 all 
printer-driver-splix/stable,now 2.0.0+svn315-7 amd64 
procps/stable,now 2:3.3.15-2 amd64 
publicsuffix/stable,now 20190415.1030-1 all 
python-apt-common/stable,stable,now 1.8.4.3 all 
python-minimal/stable,now 2.7.16-1 amd64 
python2-minimal/stable,now 2.7.16-1 amd64 
python2.7-minimal/stable,now 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 amd64 
python2.7/stable,now 2.7.16-2+deb10u1 amd64 
python2/stable,now 2.7.16-1 amd64 
python3-apt/stable,stable,now 1.8.4.3 amd64 
python3-certifi/stable,now 2018.8.24-1 all 
python3-chardet/stable,now 3.0.4-3 all 
python3-dbus/stable,now 1.2.8-3 amd64 
python3-debconf/stable,now 1.5.71 all 
python3-debian/stable,now 0.1.35 all 
python3-debianbts/stable,now 2.8.2 all 
python3-gi/stable,now 3.30.4-1 amd64 
python3-httplib2/stable,now 0.11.3-2 all 
python3-idna/stable,now 2.6-1 all 
python3-minimal/stable,now 3.7.3-1 amd64 
python3-olefile/stable,now 0.46-1 all 
python3-pexpect/stable,now 4.6.0-1 all 
python3-pil/stable,now 5.4.1-2+deb10u2 amd64 
python3-pkg-resources/stable,now 40.8.0-1 all 
python3-ptyprocess/stable,now 0.6.0-1 all 
python3-pycurl/stable,now 7.43.0.2-0.1 amd64 
python3-pysimplesoap/stable,now 1.16.2-1 all 
python3-renderpm/stable,stable,now 3.5.13-1+deb10u1 amd64 
python3-reportbug/stable,now 7.5.3~deb10u1 all 
python3-reportlab-accel/stable,stable,now 3.5.13-1+deb10u1 amd64 
python3-reportlab/stable,stable,now 3.5.13-1+deb10u1 all 
python3-requests/stable,now 2.21.0-1 all 
python3-six/stable,now 1.12.0-1 all 
python3-urllib3/stable,now 1.24.1-1 all 
python3.7-minimal/stable,now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 amd64 
python3.7/stable,now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 amd64 
python3/stable,now 3.7.3-1 amd64 
python/stable,now 2.7.16-1 amd64 
readline-common/stable,now 7.0-5 all 
reportbug/stable,now 7.5.3~deb10u1 all 
rsyslog/stable,now 8.1901.0-1 amd64 
sane-utils/stable,now 1.0.27-3.2 amd64 
sed/stable,now 4.7-1 amd64 
sensible-utils/stable,now 0.0.12 all 
shared-mime-info/stable,now 1.10-1 amd64 
ssl-cert/stable,now 1.0.39 all 
systemd-sysv/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
systemd/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
sysvinit-utils/stable,now 2.93-8 amd64 
tar/stable,now 1.30+dfsg-6 amd64 
task-english/stable,now 3.53 all 
task-laptop/stable,now 3.53 all 
task-print-server/stable,now 3.53 all 
task-ssh-server/stable,now 3.53 all 
tasksel-data/stable,now 3.53 all 
tasksel/stable,now 3.53 all 
tcl8.6/stable,now 8.6.9+dfsg-2 amd64 
tcl/stable,now 8.6.9+1 amd64 
telnet/stable,now 0.17-41.2 amd64 
tix/stable,now 8.4.3-10 amd64 
tk8.6/stable,now 8.6.9-2 amd64 
tk/stable,now 8.6.9+1 amd64 
traceroute/stable,now 1:2.1.0-2 amd64 
tzdata/stable,stable-updates,now 2021a-0+deb10u1 all 
ucf/stable,now 3.0038+nmu1 all 
udev/stable,now 241-7~deb10u6 amd64 
unzip/stable,now 6.0-23+deb10u2 amd64 
update-inetd/stable,now 4.49 all 
usb-modeswitch-data/stable,now 20170806-2 all 
usb-modeswitch/stable,now 2.5.2+repack0-2 amd64 
usb.ids/stable,now 2019.07.27-0+deb10u1 all 
usbutils/stable,now 1:010-3 amd64 
util-linux-locales/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 all 
util-linux/stable,now 2.33.1-0.1 amd64 
vim-common/stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 all 
vim-tiny/stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 amd64 
wamerican/stable,now 2018.04.16-1 all 
wget/stable,now 1.20.1-1.1 amd64 
whiptail/stable,now 0.52.20-8 amd64 
wireless-regdb/stable,now 2016.06.10-1 all 
wireless-tools/stable,now 30~pre9-13 amd64 
wpasupplicant/stable,now 2:2.7+git20190128+0c1e29f-6+deb10u2 amd64 
x11-common/stable,now 1:7.7+19 all 
x11-utils/stable,now 7.7+4 amd64 
xauth/stable,now 1:1.0.10-1 amd64 
xbitmaps/stable,now 1.1.1-2 all 
xdg-user-dirs/stable,now 0.17-2 amd64 
xkb-data/stable,now 2.26-2 all 
xterm/stable,now 344-1 amd64 
xxd/stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 amd64 
xz-utils/stable,now 5.2.4-1 amd64 
zlib1g/stable,now 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1 amd64
```